# I'm a little confused about python logic ; and my question to the modulus in determining odd and even

Tags: python

I want to ask, the code below produces triangles * which are only odd .... but I'm confused ... can anyone explain why the modulus can produce odd triangles and also why the else command is needed? (note I don't really understand modulus)

```
count = 1
while True :
    if count % 2 :
        print ('*'*count)
        count += 1

    else:
         count +=1
         continue
    
    if count > 10 :
        break
```

Comment: the `count % 2` returns remainder after dividing by 2. so for example `3 % 2` would return 1 and because 1 is truthy, the if statement would be satisfied.

Comment: Modulo is a shorthand for 'remainder'. So `count % 2` is either 1 or 0 (every whole number is either odd or even). If it's odd, print some stars, if it's even, skip that iteration in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `if (count % 2):`  means if the count is odd.

Explanation:

`count % 2`

- will always equal 0 if count is an even number
- will always equal 1 if count is an odd number
- `if count % 2` when `count` is odd breaks down to `if 1` which is always True
- `if count % 2`  when `count` is even breaks down to `if 0` which is always False

For your second question the else actually isn't necessary, it could be rewritten like this

```
count = 1
while True:
    if count % 2 :
        print ('*'*count)
    count += 1
    if count > 10 :
        break
```

When you consider a standard equalateral triangle made of `*`:

this is what it looks like using only odd numbers..

```
       *
      ***
     *****
    *******
   *********
  ***********
 *************
```

this is what it would look like using evens and odds

```
      *
     **
    ***
   ****
  *****
 ******
*******
```

Comment: thank you, can you give an example .... the logic if making a triangle is only even?

Comment: @RezaWahyuRamadhan  It's the other way around... It only uses the odd numbers.  But it doesn't have to be that way.... you can make a triangle from odds and evens It looks better when you start at 1 and stack every other number of stars.... see my example.

Comment: @RezaWahyuRamadhan using only even wouldn't really work that well because you have to skip 1 which should always be the peak of the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Modulus in this case differentiates between odd and even numbers. In your case, as you can see in the printed pyramid, you only have odd values - 1,3,5 etc. You are in the "if" part when you have an even number, and in the else part for the off.

I suggest you put more print statements in the program to see it's behavior in greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` condition checks for return value equal 1, not 0. But, if you put `if(count % 2 == 0)` for example, you will notice non-odd print output.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic could potentially be simplified:

```py
for i in range(1, 12, 2):
    print('*' * i)
```

**Explanation:**

The `range` operator accepts a `stop` value (non-inclusive) and a `step` value, which defaults to 1. Here we pass `step=2`, so we only iterate over the odd numbers in the range.

**Out:**

```
*
***
*****
*******
*********
***********
```

Answer (score 0):

Modulo, or [modular division](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/what-is-modular-arithmetic) is like grade school integer division where you don't compute a decimal part, but rather just a whole part, and a remainder. Specifically modulo throws out the whole part, and only keeps the remainder. The opposite of that is integer division, which throws out the remainder: `9//2 == 4 #quotient` `9%2 == 1 #remainder`

- `while True:` Do this forever (or until `break` or an uncaught error)

  - `if (count % 2):` Do this if count is Odd: `(count % 2)` will be 1 if odd, and 0 if even. 1 will cast to True, and 0 will cast to False for the `if` condition.

    - `print('*'*count)` construct a string by repeating the string `"*"` by `count` times, and `print` it.
    - `count += 1` increment the count variable
  - `else` do this if count is even (corollary to prior statement)

    - `count += 1` increment the count variable
  - `if count > 10:` when count variable is greater than 10

    - `break` exit the `while True` loop